# Unable to access file from share drive using fopen in C (windows)

Tags: c, windows, fopen

I am taking share drive path as input and adding extra '\' and assigning to a variable.If I use this variable for opening file with "fopen" error is thrown as "No such file or directory".

But If I give the same path (with extra '\' in the path) in the code itself I am able to access.

command: program `\\xyz\abc.txt` (program_name )

1) My code which doesn't work is like this:

In the program I am making the passed in input path as `"\\\\xyz\\abc.txt"` by adding extra "\".

then, fopen(var_name,"r"); /* Not working*/

2) Code which works fine:

```
char arr[100] = "\\\\xyz\\abc.txt"

fopen(arr,"r"); /* works fine */
```

It seems if the path is known at compile time itself it is working but not at run time.Please suggest what can I do to access path from input not hard coded in program.

Comment: As a member for such a long you should really have had plenty of time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You don't need to add the `\\` at runtime; this is only necessary at compilation time. You, the user, _might_ need to escape the backslashes when _running_ the program, depending on which shell you're using and how you quote your arguments.

Comment: @Roger Lipscombe thanks for reply. The same code works fine for local drive like C:\ or D:\ I am facing the issue only with share drives.

Comment: Normally, on stared drives, the first part of a file name is the name of the 'share' preceeded by 2 slashes.  I.E. `\\<sharename>\<path>\<filename>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash in filepath during compile time.. i.e. 
"\xyz\abc.txt" but runtime has only one slash.

Piece of code to read input from user:

char filename[50];
FILE *fp;

printf("Enter the filename \n");
gets(filename);

fp = fopen(filename, "r");

Comment: the function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely eliminated in the latest C standard.  Much better to use `fgets()` then remove the trailing newline character

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: @Archie Yalakki Thanks for the answer. It helped me.